# Excel VBA on Range Error - Quick Fix?

Tags: vba, excel

The below code gives an error but when I change the range to `.Range(A2:A9999)` it works...

But it's ugly. Is there way to grab all the data in column(A) from A2 and down? and copy that into B2?

```
Sheets("AA").Range("A2:A").Value = Sheets("BB").Range("B2:B").Value
```

Comment: You are also saying that you want to copy from A to B, but your code attempts to copy from B to A.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To have it in one line you can do it as follows:

```
Sheets("AA").Range("A2", Cells(Rows.Count, "A")).Copy Sheets("BB").Range("B2")
```

By the way, it copies everything, not only values but also formatting. To run it your sheet AA should be active one.

Answer (score 1):

By finding the last populated cell in column A, you can be more precise in what you are copying.

This copies the contents of column A on the src sheet to column B of the tgt sheet:

```
Sub CopyOneColumnToAnother()
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim src As Worksheet
    Dim tgt As Worksheet
    Dim lastRow As Long

    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set src = wb.Sheets("Sheet5")
    Set tgt = wb.Sheets("Sheet6")
    lastRow = src.Range("A" & src.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    tgt.Range("B2:B" & lastRow).Value = src.Range("A2:A" & lastRow).Value
End Sub
```

The reason you are getting the error is because your ranges don't have valid end points. `Range ([firstcell]:[lastcell])` is the correct syntax, so you need to add a row for the lastcell in both your source and target ranges.

Note that even if your code runs, it won't do want you want. You are setting column A to equal column B. You need to flip the left and right-hand sides of your statement.

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer but I am trying to copy it from one sheet to another. (sheet 1 to sheet 2). This only copies column within the same sheet.

Comment: I see. I've edited the answer to copy from one sheet to another. Try it now. (Change Sheet5 and Sheet6 to 1 and 2, or whatever is in your workbook.)

Answer (score 1):

```
Sub CopyValues()

    Dim rValues As Range

    With Sheet1
        Set rValues = .Range("A2", .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp))
    End With

    rValues.Offset(, 1).Value = rValues.Value

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just copy the whole column and re-insert whatever was in B1:

```
Range("A:A").Copy Columns("B:B")
Range("B1").Value = "Whatever"
```

In more detail:

```
Dim previous 'As Variant (or whatever it is)

previous = Worksheets("BB").Range("B1").Value
Worksheets("AA").Range("A:A").Copy Worksheets("BB").Columns("B:B")
Worksheets("BB").Range("B1").Value = previous
```

Unless there is data further down in column B which you wish to keep (you haven't stated).